# Error when adding to cart in Magento2

Tags: magento2, addtocart

I have a Magento 2 Installation in which everything appears to be working fine **except** products will not add to the cart. The add to cart button appears to do nothing at all. I am getting the following error in console from `knockout.js file line:3012`

```
Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "css: function (){return { empty:cart().summary_count == 0} }"
Message: cart is not a function
```

Has anyone experienced anything similar? I cannot find any documentation on similar issues with Magento2.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Daniel, do you have customizations, css changes, js changes? Do you use development mode? Please clarify. thanks

Comment: What's the version of magento you use? Did you have magento 2 previously installed on this domain? Did you clear browser cache?

Comment: @MaxPronko Yes! A piece of JavaScript in a custom theme was causing the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved. Some unknown JavaScript in a custom theme was clashing with some part of the Add to Cart process. I reverted to a default theme and the issue was resolved.

Comment: Its been a while, but could you clarify which JS exactly destroyed knockout.js? Am having the same issue and struggeling to find that JS code.

Comment: @Max Apologies Max, but I don't remember. It was nothing within an existing Magento theme, only some minor functionality I had implemented to show/hide elements if I remember correctly. Be sure to use .noConflict. Good luck!